# Convert SVG with foreign objects to zoomable PDF javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jspdf

I want to convert an SVG to PDF file on the frontend. I am using React and drawing a chart using d3 and I want to be to print the chart as a PDF. However, all of the solutions I have tried dont work for some reason. Mostly due to the fact that my chart includes foreignObjects as nodes.

The only working solution I have is through html2canvas and jsPDF. I convert the svg to canvas and then png and later print it using jspdf this solution prints the graph correctly but as it prints as an image the text is pixelated as I zoom in. I am looking for a solution that allows me to zoom in without breaking quality ( I dont know if thats even possible, even if it is upto 200% it should work)

I would like to know any suggestions you may have